# How to fix "Failed to create graphics device.Exiting" error?

Tags: graphics, windows-7, nvidia, video-card

Win7(64), nvdia 960. 
All of a sudden 90% of my games stopped working. My oldest game (GOC 1998) works using dxwnd. My newest game (For Honor-online 2017) still works, but Total War,  Tropico4 and Americas Army doesnt detect my graphics card anymore. Ive reinstalled drivers,games,contacted MSFT and Nvidia support but keep getting graphics errors. I think a recent MSFt update fugged something.
Has anyone else had this error?
Tried to update my BIOS step by step but get the "bad command" error. That's another topic i may start.

Answer (score 0):

Use DDU http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html

Install latest Nvidia drivers

Make sure you have latest chipset drivers for your motherboard installed.

If all else fails, open cmd as admin and run sfc /scannow

Comment: Sorry for delay,had sign in issues. I Installed latest Nvidia drivers multiple times using DDU.Removed gfx card, blew air in card and mobo socket and reinstalled.SFC showed no integrity violations. I tried to install intel graphics driver but i get an error saying my system isnt supported when it is; i5-4690,win7,8gb ram etc. I disconnected my IGD trying to fix this, but I had this issue before that. Still trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by doing what I was trying to avoid, **reinstalled the entire OS**.

It appeared to be corrupt or missing windows drivers, possibly msft vc 2008 x64,x86 version(9.0.30729.6161) and msft vc 2010 x64,x86 version(10.0.40219) along with a ton of other drivers during reinstall. It took about 3+ hours.